# Discord bot can't be disconnected - python 3.8

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to disconnect my bot from channel when nobody is in channel with bot, so i did this:

```py
async def check():
    member_count = len(client.voice_clients)
    if not member_count > 1:
        await voice.disconnect()
```

this function is being called every 60 seconds

and it gives me this error:
`NameError: name 'voice' is not defined`

so i added voice definition from leave function:

```py
async def check():
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    member_count = len(client.voice_clients)
    print(member_count)
    if not member_count > 1:
        await voice.disconnect()
```

but it gives me new error:
`NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined`

Is there any fix to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    voice_state = member.guild.voice_client
    if voice_state is None:
        return

    if len(voice_state.channel.members) == 1:
        await voice_state.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

ctx is your command context provided by the discord.command system. for internal tasks you can't use that, because it has no actual message the bot activity is caused by.

To solve your problem, you have to access your guild in a different way. For example by client.guilds or client.get_guild(guild_id)

Comment: more about the context you can learn here https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#context